# how to work with @scheduled annotation in spring

Tags: java, spring, cron

I have to read time of a file(video) created and if the time of file is greater than 3 days i have to delete the files. For this i have used @scheduled annotation in spring. But when i run the application, that deletion code is not working. I have configured `xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd
<task:annotation-driven />` in spring xml file. It is showing schema reference 4:failed to read. So i have decided to use complete annotation. java version is 7 and spring version is 4.2.2. I have set cron expression at  4 PM and I ran application at 3.58 PM. Nothing executed. What am I missing. What is the best package(controller/service/secondary logic) to place this code. And I would also like to know How to implement DELETE method. This is my code for deleting videos

```
package com.test.logic;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Date;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import com.sun.xml.internal.ws.developer.SchemaValidation;

@Component
@EnableScheduling
public class VideoDelete {
    @Scheduled(cron="* 1-15 16 * * * *")
    public void deleteVideo(){
    System.out.println("========> $$$$$$ scheduler method is executed $$$$$ <==========");
        long presentTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
        Date presentDate=new Date(presentTime);
        File file=new File("E://videorecording1");
        File[] fileList=file.listFiles();
        for (File files : fileList){
            if (files.isFile()){
                long filecreatedtime=files.lastModified();
                Date fileDate=new Date(filecreatedtime);
                long difference = presentDate.getTime() - fileDate.getTime();
                long hoursDifference = difference / (60 * 60 * 1000);
                if(hoursDifference >= 72)
                    files.delete();
            }
        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Spring scheduler's cron allows only 6 kind of triggers.
From the official documentation:

> A cron-like expression, extending the usual UN*X definition to
>   include triggers
>   * on the second as well as minute, hour, day of month, month and day of week.

To be able to support 7 trigger(including the YEAR) you have to use Quartz:https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/ 
In your current case try this:

```
(cron = "0 0 16 * * ?")
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you will be better of trying with cron expression `"*/10 * * * * *` which basically means method will be executed every 10 seconds with no hour/date/day limitation.
This way you will see if there's anything wrong with spring configuration itself or files permission.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution. The reason is spring container is not recognizing VideoDelete class as a spring bean. So i have annotated it with @controller and now it is working fine.

Comment: It should have recognize it beacuse of '@Component' annotation.

Comment: yeah that's what i am wondering, i have placed that code in logic package and with '@component' it has to work. Is there any possible reason why it is not working. But when i place the code in controller package with '@controller' it is working.